# ODBC Data Source Administrator with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have scoured Stack Overflow and the internet in general for steps leading to an answer, but have as of yet been unsuccessful.  My main goal is to use ASP scripts with MS SQL databases on my standalone Win7 PC, but the short term goal is to be able to configure an ODBC User or File DSN connection that tests successfully in the ODBC Data Source Administrator.

I have SQL Server 2012 installed and can successfully connect to the database engine from SQL Server Management Studio.

When I try to configure a DSN entry in ODBC, the error message reads

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

All attempts to test the data source lead to a  15-second time-out with the TESTS FAILED! message.

I have tried all of the usually recommended adjustments.  What other details could I provide?  HELP!!

Comment: wow, I have exactly the same problem. Searching google led to me to this post. Shame there is no answer!

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes is disabled by default. You need to enable it from the Sql Server Configuration Manager if you want to connect over named pipes.

```
SQL Server 2017; SQLServerManager14.msc
SQL Server 2016; SQLServerManager13.msc
SQL Server 2014; SQLServerManager12.msc
SQL Server 2012 (11.x); SQLServerManager11.msc
```

You will need to use one of these .msc files from START > RUN to open the Sql Server Configuration Manager

I have SQL Server 2017 so I will give you steps for that.

```
1. Start
2. Run
3. Type in SQLServerManager14.msc and hit OK

The SQL Server Configuration Manager will open.

4. In the left pane of the Configuration Manager, look for "SQL Server Network Configuration" and expand it.
5. Find the "Protocols for {Your Server}" and double click it. There could be multiple options here if you have multiple SQL Server
Instances running on the server. Make sure you are updating the
Protocols for the correct instance(s).
6. Double click named pipes and change it from disabled to enabled
7. Restart your SQL Server services

You will now be able to connect over named pipes.
```